# How can I use the success and failure data to estimate parameters of a Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: probability-distribution

I have used Beta function to estimate the performance of the agent. I have failure and success data of the task that runs on the agent. 
The parameter $\alpha$ is a number of successful tasks, while $\beta$ is the number of failures. Thus, I can estimate the performance by exploiting the expected value of Beta, as $$\mu = \frac{\alpha} {(\alpha+\beta)}$$

So, I am looking for a similar model, such that its parameter can be estimated from the success and failure data. So far I found Dirichlet distribution.

What is the expected value of Dirichlet distribution? How I can use the success and failure data to estimate parameters of this distribution?

Let's check the following example:

Suppose that we use a Dirichlet prior represented by $Dirichlet(1, 1, 1)$ and observe $13$ results with $8$ Successful, $2$ Missing, and $3$ Failures. Then we get the posterior to be $Dirichlet(1+8, 1+2, 1+3)$. Then if you define the performance value $\alpha$ to be the expectation of $P(x=Successful)$, 
then $\alpha$ will be $(1+8)/[(1+8)+(1+2)+(1+3)] = 0.56$

Now 
Suppose that we use a Beta prior represented by $Beta(1,1)$ and observe $13$ results with $8$ Successful, and $3$ Failures. Then we get the posterior to be $Beta(1+8, 1+3)$. Then if you define the performance value Pr to be the expectation of $P(x=Successful)$, 
then $\alpha = (1+8)/[(1+8)+(1+3)] = 0.69$

Are my calculations and concept right?

Comment: Is this problem in the context of reinforcement learning? So, is your agent an RL agent?

Comment: Actually no, but thanks for this good idea, seems interesting

Comment: Your calculations seems correct but I dont know about its effectiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirichlet is the Multi Variate version of the Beta distribution. In general, these distributions can be thought to model the probability of modelling a probability distribution.

The [support](https://www.statlect.com/glossary/support-of-a-random-variable) Dirichlet distribution is defined as follows:

$$ S_K = \{ x:0 \leq x_k \leq 1, \sum_{k=1}^K x_k=1 \} $$

and the PDF is defined as:

$$Dir(x|\alpha) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha)} \prod_{k=1}^Kx_k^{\alpha_k-1}$$

where $B(\alpha)$ is the beta function of $K$ variables:

$$B(\alpha) = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^K \tau(\alpha_k)}{\tau(\sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k)}$$

and the resultant point estimates are (Define $\sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k = \alpha_0)$:

$$\mu(x_k) = \frac{\alpha_k}{\alpha_0}$$
$$\sigma^2(x_k) = \frac{\alpha_k(\alpha_0-\alpha_k)}{\alpha_0^2(\alpha_0+1)}$$
$$mode[x_k] = \frac{\alpha_k-1}{\alpha_0-1}$$

Beta distribution is the special case where $k=2$

Clearly, when you run an experiment a large number of times, the success of each $k$ will approach towards its expected value i.e if you define your random variables as $x_k = \frac{N_{k}}{N}$ where $N$ is the total number of trials and $N_k$ is the success of the $k$ th term, it clearly satisfies the support of the Dirichlet Distribution and hence you can use

$$\frac{\alpha_{k}}{\alpha_0} = \frac{N_{k}}{N}$$

This is assuming that the experiment follows Dirichlet Distribution.

(Taken in parts from [A Probabilistic Approach to ML](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/))

Comment: many thanks, @DuttaA. This is a good explanation.  Let me ask this If we assign an agent with 13 jobs to represent as x. Then 10 success, and 3 failure. I Beta: With prior, B(1,1) we will get `Performance = E(x) = 10+1/(10+3+2) = 0.73`. In Dirichlet we will have `Performance = E(x) = 10/13 = 0.76`. Is this correct? I mean Numerator and denominator are same in Beta as well

Comment: @jou Like I said in my answer beta is a single/special case of Dirichlet distribution (with k=2, just put k=2 in my Dirichlet formula and see, $\alpha_1 = \alpha$ while $\alpha_2 = \beta$), and hence results should remain same for same case. While Beta will deal with  a single agent (in your case) Beta deals with multiple agents. In your case you are treating a single agents success and failure, whereas another way to look at it is failure of one agent is success of another. Thus in Dirichlet, success belongs to a single agent while the rest fails.

Comment: Many thanks @DuttaA. I study your formula, and I write an example to clarify any misusing. Kindly read my updated post again to read my example.